# jQuery illuminate in use with bootstrap 2.2.2 won't work together: e.css(...) is undefined illuminate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I've downloaded and set up jQuery illuminate( http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-illuminate/ )
I made sure both jQuery and illuminate plugin are loaded in page.

Then I coded like this

**Javascript part**

```
window.onload = function(){
            if(document.URL.indexOf("mode=1") >= 0){ 

                    var input = $(".box#input");
                    $(document).scrollTop(input .offset().top - 60);
                    var v = input.val();
                    input.val('');
                    input.focus().val(v);
                    input.focus()

                    $(".btn#illuminate").illuminate({
                        'intensity': '0.3',
                        'color': '#98cb00',
                        'blink': 'true',
                        'blinkSpeed': '1200',
                        'outerGlow': 'true',
                        'outerGlowSize': '30px',
                        'outerGlowColor': '#98cb00'
                    });

            }
}
```

**Form part**

```
<div class="chat">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments" class="new_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_comment" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="GujuDnihu2UXCbJgbooDxoikjcJncFLf8hl4=" /></div>
        <div class="input-append">
            <input class="box" id="input" name="comment[body]" type="text" value="Hello there" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn" id="illuminate">submit</button>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

However, the submit button won't illuminate.
I see the error that says `e.css(...) is undefined     illuminate.js`
Why? how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure those are valid jQuery selectors?

Comment: illuminate and jQuery are loaded in the right order?

Comment: so you've included jQuery, jQuery UI and Illuminate in that order?

Comment: line "input.focus()" needs a semicolon (;) at it's end.

Comment: @Shebo That would not be a problem. It is at least a warning...

Comment: Probably unrelated, but there's a rogue `</div>` on the line with `<form ...`.

Comment: Mind creating a fiddle? Would make debugging easier

Comment: @OptimusPrime It doesn't work:(

Comment: @John what do you mean?

Comment: @koala_dev jQuery is loaded first.

Comment: @Shebo Thanks. I fixed it but no change:(

Comment: @MKK, when i first loaded the question, there was no HTML code displayed. Disregard

Comment: @OptimusPrime It doesn't matter. because everything else except illuminating is working

Comment: Seems to me you are using selectors wrong. When you have a unique id, use id only to select element. `#illuminate` and '#input'

Comment: @MKK What happens if you use `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` instead of `window.onload = function () { ... }`?

Comment: This is weird. Everything is working except illuminating part but in this jsfiddle nothing happens http://jsfiddle.net/b82fW/

Comment: working now : http://jsfiddle.net/b82fW/1/
added jquery and added the illuminate code BEFORE the code uve typed

Comment: oops..tested on chrome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other users above already mentioned that a few selectors could be changed so instead of using `$(".box#input");` you could use `$("#input");` since an id wihtin a page must be unique and therefore the additional class selector `.box` is not needed. I tested in the chrome dev tools if the selector was the cause for the error but at least in chrome 30 it does not matter.

I copied your html unchanged and ran it locally - it worked as expected the button glows.

Then i created an **[online demo plunk at plnkr.co](http://embed.plnkr.co/3zViuRtIbxNaSdcJ5KYx/preview)** and changed only a few things:

1. nesting of divs
2. removal of `document.URL.indexOf("mode=1") >= 0` so that it works with any url

So this is the html

```
<div>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/comments" class="new_comment" 
    data-remote="true" 
    id="new_comment" method="post">
    <div class="chat">
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
      <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
          value="GujuDnihu2UXCbJgbooDxoikjcJncFLf8hl4=" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="box" id="input" name="comment[body]" 
               type="text" value="Hello there" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn" 
               id="illuminate">submit</button>
    </div>
</form> 
</div>
```

And it seems to work just fine. Let me know if it does not work as expected. The error mus lie somewhere else.

- What version of jquery, jquery-ui and illuminate are you using?

#### Update: Information from our chat

I understood the following:

- you are using jquery v1.9.1
- bootstrap 2.2.2
- jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.8.24 (may be [this one](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)?)
- currently you are **not** including [any version of jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js)

The next step is to include a reference to jquery-ui.min.js and the see if this works together with bootsrap.

#### Update 2: jQuery illuminate in use with jQuery 1.9.1

Using the [illuminate 0.7 plugin](http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-illuminate/) with jQuery 1.9.1 **[requires a modified version of illuminate 0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043125/plugin-illuminate-0-7-incompatible-to-jquery-1-9-1-or-jquery-ui-1-10-3-typeer)**

Comment: I'm using bootstrap. and the button and text field are shown with that. Does it matter???

Comment: You didn't change any from my codes right? including javascript.  If so, there should be something wrong with other code in the same page:(

Comment: This could very well be. I do not know if there is a naming or function conflict between the two. Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: If possible could you do that with jsfiddle? so that I can paste my whole bootstrap css

Comment: I added bootstrap css. http://jsfiddle.net/b82fW/5/ Please see this. It doesn't illuminate:( I use FireFox and it's working on official website. I see it illuminating. but not on this fiddle:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34783/discussion-between-threefouronesixonethree-and-mkk)

Comment: Yes it was all because of the difference of version